# Build error when binding a `RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource` to a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I'm getting the following error when using `RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource` to a UITableView's `rx_itemsAnimatedWithDataSource()`.

Here's a screengrab of the error:

[image: Xcode Error]

> Cannot invoke 'rx_itemsAnimatedWithDataSource' with an argument list
>   of type
>   '(RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource)'
>
> Expected an argument list of type '(DataSource)'

`self.dataSource` is of type:

`RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource< DateSelectorSectionModel>`

and here's the generated interface for `DateSelectorSectionModel`, plus related types:

```
typealias DateSelectorSectionModel = SectionModel<SectionDesc, SectionDesc>

enum SectionType {
    case StartDate, EndDate, TimeZone, AllDay
}

enum SectionState {
    case Present, Missing, Dirty
}

enum SectionSelection {
    case NotSelected, Selected
}

struct SectionDesc {
    var type: SectionType
    var state: SectionState
    var selectionState: SectionSelection
    init(type: SectionType, state: SectionState, selection: SectionSelection)
    public func getSectionModel() -> DateSelectorSectionModel
}

extension EventDetailsDateSelectorViewModel {
    public var rows: RxCocoa.Driver<[DateSelectorSectionModel]> { get }
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

For Animated dataSources, the correct model should be of type `HashableSectionModel`.  Which means that :

```
// Instead of this:
typealias DateSelectorSectionModel = SectionModel<SectionDesc, SectionDesc>
// Do this:
typealias DateSelectorSectionModel = HashableSectionModel<SectionDesc, SectionDesc>
```

With this change, everything compiles as expected.